# Java default Locale fallback

Tags: java, internationalization, globalization

In Java I create Locale with Language and Country parameters
and then use appropriate date formats.

However Java does not support all Language_Country combinations and fallbacks to default locale formats (in my case en_US).

Is there a way to determine that fallback occured?

E.g:

When I create locale with `Locale locale = new Locale("xx","xx");`

then

`((SimpleDateFormat)DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT,locale)).toLocalizedPattern();`

returns `M/d/yy` so it fallbacks to en_US.

So i need something like

`locale.isDefault`

Comment: Have you tried to `Locale.setDefault()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check that the locale is one of [the available locales](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#getAvailableLocales%28%29):

```
Set<Locale> locales = new HashSet<>();
Collections.addAll(locales, Locale.getAvailableLocales());

Locale locale = new Locale("xx", "xx");
System.out.println(locales.contains(locale)); //prints false

locale = new Locale("fr", "FR");
System.out.println(locales.contains(locale)); //prints true
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be what i'm looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

Locale.getDefault().equals(locale)

Comment: unfortunately it returns false for locale xx_XX